# Wifi adapter showing, drivers installed, but no networks in network list

Tags: windows-10

I've completely formatted my machine, and reinstalled Windows 10. I've installed the correct driver (AWUS036NHA) from here: https://files.alfa.com.tw/?dir=%5B1%5D%20WiFi%20USB%20adapter/AWUS036NHA/Windows

The card shows in the adapters and lights up and start flashing after the driver is installed. But when I click the network icon in the task bar no networks show. I've checked the adapter and it shows in the adapter list with a red X next to it.

The driver properties for the device are showing as working. I've attempted to update drivers but the dialog tells me I already have the latest drivers.

The only thing I haven't done is ran an update after installing Windows 10 because for some unknown reason my ISP is blocking addresses required and returns a connection error. This happens from time to time with my current ISP.

I'm trying to figure out how to get the networks to show up in the network list. The same card works on my other Windows 10 machine so I can't understand what's happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would try again to update (you say it will at some point) and restart the computer.  You may wish to restart anyway right now to see if that brings back the display of active networks.

Comment: I realized I was using 1903 build which is now unsupported. I'm re downloading the latest build and seeing if that helps. Is it possible that without the update on 1903 that could be causing this?

Comment: That is hard to say. I have had Windows 10 on this machine from V1511 forward and wireless has always worked. But once or twice in several years the display does not show and I just restart. But here, I would certainly update.

Comment: have you ever tried to "Network Reset" in the settings>networking&Internet?

Comment: Yes I tried this. It turns out the adapter was faulty.